# Enable modules across platforms using Features/Drush

Tags: drush, features

I am wondering, could this be automated.

1. I download and enable contrib modules on @dev
2. I push files on @live (including new modules)
3. via Features/Drush I tell @live to enable new modules, so servers are in sync.

I do some needed disabling/enabling of dev modules when doing sql-sync to @dev, but this is case when I install new modules on @dev and want them on @live automagically when I commit.

I could, of course, do **drush @live en [modulename]** for each module I installed on dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this could be automated. I'd suggest the missing component is git or possibly another source control tool, so you can create commits that represent complete sets of configuration changes.

(I see you mention commit in your question so presumably you already use git).

Comment: I do not commit using git (as it is overhead for single-developer maintained project), I "commit" using drush rsync. But that does not enable module on target (Even if I commited from git, modules would not be enabled). I am wondering if module state (enabled/disabled) can be captured in features, or they can be enabled via Drush in bulk.